# Page looks nothing like page layout

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, page-layout

super new to Salesforce. We have a custom object called "Evaluator."

However, when we created different layouts for this object. However, the page layout editor looks *nothing* like the actual page itself. I can't figure out what's wrong. I tried all the panels from the Setup>Object Manager>Evaluator (Page Layouts, Lightning Record Pages, Compact Layouts) and nothing looks anything like the actual live pages.

Comment: you should use [edit] and post some screenshots

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you checked the Trailhead tutorials [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-knowledge-setup-and-customization/configure-page-layouts-and-record-types) and [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_page_layouts)?

Comment: There are several layers to how a record page looks to a user. The Lightning Record Page assigned, the Page Layout assigned (if the Lightning Record page uses the Details or Related List(s) components), and the field-level security all play a role, As said above, screenshots would help a lot.